# How to make drop down box bring above and in fron to the all content in pure css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created custom drop down like div's. But the problem I am facing is with `display` the `ul`.

**Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Drop Downn</title>
</head>

<style>

    .content{
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: aliceblue;
    }
    .combo-box{

        border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.089);
        background-color: #ffffff;
        width: 200px;
        height: 40px;

        font-size: 18px;

        cursor: pointer;

        align-items: center;
        display: flex;
    }

    .selections{

        background-color: beige;
    }

    ul{

    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;


    background-color: white;

    border: 1px solid rgba(97, 97, 97, 0.164);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 6px -2px #00000036;

    width: 200px;
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;

    display: none;
  }

  li{

    list-style: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0px 14px;
    height: 32px;

    line-height: 34px;

  }

 li:hover{

    background-color: rgb(216, 9, 95);
    color: white;
 }

</style>

<script>

    function display(tag){

        let div = document.getElementsByTagName(tag)[0]
        div.style.display = div.style.display != 'block' ? 'block' : 'none'
    }
</script>
<body>

    <div class="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nam laudantium possimus nulla officia tempore earum ea perspiciatis quia fugit asperiores laborum ab voluptas, dolore doloremque illo? Saepe, ex? Molestiae, doloremque?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="selections">
        <h4>Select your pet</h4>

    <div class="combo-box" onclick="display('ul')">
        <a>Tiger</a>
    </div>

    <ul>
        <li>Cat</li>
        <li>Dog</li>
        <li>Tiger</li>
        <li>Lion</li>
        <li>Parrot</li>
        <li>Peacock</li>
        <li>Rabbit</li>
        <li>Raino</li>
        <li>Kola</li>
        <li>Sea Lion</li>
        <li>Otter</li>
        <li>Turtle</li>
        <li>Rat</li>
        <li>Cow</li>
        <li>Goat</li>
        <li>Pig</li>
        <li>Fish (Fish food)</li>
        <li>Owl</li>
        <li>Squirrel</li>
    </ul>        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

[image]
From above picture, I want to show `ul` list over all div's & above the box `Tiger` and I don't want to expand the div `selections`. How can I make it work like that? Thank you all.

**Update:**
  I want to show the drop down above the `.combo-box`. Please refer below code and screenshot.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Drop Downn</title>
  </head>

  <style>
    .content {
      height: 400px;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: aliceblue;
    }

    .combo-box {
      position: relative;   /* <-- Relative position here */

      border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.089);
      background-color: #ffffff;
      width: 200px;
      height: 40px;

      font-size: 18px;

      cursor: pointer;

      align-items: center;
      display: flex;
    }

    .selections {
      background-color: beige;
    }

    ul {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      background-color: white;

      border: 1px solid rgba(97, 97, 97, 0.164);
      box-shadow: 0 1px 6px -2px #00000036;

      width: 200px;
      max-height: 300px;
      overflow: auto;

      display: none;
    }

    li {

      list-style: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 0px 14px;
      height: 32px;

      line-height: 34px;

    }

    li:hover {

      background-color: rgb(216, 9, 95);
      color: white;
    }

  </style>

  <script>
    function display(tag) {

      let div = document.getElementsByTagName(tag)[0]
      div.style.display = div.style.display != 'block' ? 'block' : 'none'
    }

  </script>

  <body>

    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nam laudantium possimus nulla officia tempore earum ea perspiciatis quia fugit asperiores laborum ab voluptas, dolore doloremque illo? Saepe, ex? Molestiae, doloremque?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="selections">
      <h4>Select your pet</h4>

      <ul>
        <li>Cat</li>
        <li>Dog</li>
        <li>Tiger</li>
        <li>Lion</li>
        <li>Parrot</li>
        <li>Peacock</li>
        <li>Rabbit</li>
        <li>Raino</li>
        <li>Kola</li>
        <li>Sea Lion</li>
        <li>Otter</li>
        <li>Turtle</li>
        <li>Rat</li>
        <li>Cow</li>
        <li>Goat</li>
        <li>Pig</li>
        <li>Fish (Fish food)</li>
        <li>Owl</li>
        <li>Squirrel</li>
      </ul>

      <div class="combo-box" onclick="display('ul')">
        <a>Tiger</a>    
      </div>


    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Output I want like below image, but I don't want to expand that div.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By reviewing the structure of your `html` and using the property `position: absolute` you can achieve something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Drop Downn</title>
</head>

<style>
  .content {
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: aliceblue;
  }
  
  .combo-box {
    position: relative;
    /* <-- Relative position here */
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.089);
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
  }
  
  .selections {
    background-color: beige;
  }
  
  ul {
    position: absolute;
    /* <-- Absolute position here */
    bottom: 100%;
    /* <-- Fix it to bottom */
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid rgba(97, 97, 97, 0.164);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 6px -2px #00000036;
    width: 200px;
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
    display: none;
  }
  
  li {
    list-style: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0px 14px;
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 34px;
  }
  
  li:hover {
    background-color: rgb(216, 9, 95);
    color: white;
  }
</style>

<script>
  function display(tag) {

    let div = document.getElementsByTagName(tag)[0]
    div.style.display = div.style.display != 'block' ? 'block' : 'none'
  }
</script>

<body>

  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nam laudantium possimus nulla officia tempore earum ea perspiciatis quia fugit asperiores laborum ab voluptas, dolore doloremque illo? Saepe, ex? Molestiae, doloremque?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="selections">
    <h4>Select your pet</h4>

    <div class="combo-box" onclick="display('ul')">
      <a>Tiger</a>

      <!-- Move ul in .combo-box -->
      <ul>
        <li>Cat</li>
        <li>Dog</li>
        <li>Tiger</li>
        <li>Lion</li>
        <li>Parrot</li>
        <li>Peacock</li>
        <li>Rabbit</li>
        <li>Raino</li>
        <li>Kola</li>
        <li>Sea Lion</li>
        <li>Otter</li>
        <li>Turtle</li>
        <li>Rat</li>
        <li>Cow</li>
        <li>Goat</li>
        <li>Pig</li>
        <li>Fish (Fish food)</li>
        <li>Owl</li>
        <li>Squirrel</li>
      </ul>
    </div>


  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It works for overlay of all views. But not expected I requested. Please look up question update. Could this possible? Thank you for your valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

Give `position:absolute` to ul tag. will work for you.

```
ul{
position: absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
bottom:0;
right: 0;
}
.combo-box{
position: relative
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But It's not working expected. The list `ul` gone top of the document. Please refer the out put image.  https://ibb.co/2Fd70wY